# Solving two coupled PDEs using two methods, how to calculate the error between them in theory?

Tags: pde

Assumed I have the following coupled PDEs with the variables $A(z,t)$ and $B(z,t)$ and the constants $c_1,\,c_2$:
$$\begin{split}
\partial_tA&=\partial_zA+c_1\left(A+B\right)\\
\partial_tB&=\partial_zB+c_2\left(A+B\right)
\end{split}
$$
Now I have seen this algorithm for solving those equations:
First, calculate the first equation using
$$\left(1-\frac{dt}{2}\partial_z\right)A_{n+1}=\left(1+\frac{dt}{2}\partial_z\right)A_n+dt\cdot c_1(A_n+B_n)$$
and then use the solution in the second equation as:
$$\left(1-\frac{dt}{2}\partial_z\right)B_{n+1}=\left(1+\frac{dt}{2}\partial_z\right)B_n+dt\cdot c_2(A_{n+1}+B_n)$$
I would have approached it differently by combining $A$ and $B$ into a vector $C$:
$$\begin{split}
C_{n+1}&=\begin{pmatrix}A_{n+1}\\B_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}\\
C_{n}&=\begin{pmatrix}A_{n}\\B_{n}\end{pmatrix}
\end{split}$$
and then expanding the corresponding matrices:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1-\frac{dt}{2}\partial_z-dt\frac{c_1}{2}&-dt\frac{c_1}{2}\\
-dt\frac{c_2}{2}&1-\frac{dt}{2}\partial_z-dt\frac{c_2}{2}
\end{pmatrix}C_{n+1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1+\frac{dt}{2}\partial_z+dt\frac{c_1}{2}&dt\frac{c_1}{2}\\
dt\frac{c_2}{2}&1+\frac{dt}{2}\partial_z+dt\frac{c_2}{2}
\end{pmatrix}C_n
$$
Is my approach "more" correct than the initial one? If yes, how can I estimate my error and compare it to the original approach?

Comment: You can expand $A_{n+1}$ using Taylor series about $A_{n}$ in terms of $\Delta t$ and $\Delta x$. Repeat this for $B_{n+1}$ as well. 

Then write down the equations for $A_{n+1}^{(1)}, B_{n+1}^{(1)}$ and $A_{n+1}^{(2)}, B_{n+1}^{(2)}$. 

On subtracting the two sets of equations, you will be left with two equations, one for $A_{n+1}^{(1)} - A_{n+1}^{(2)}$ and another similarly for B. You should notice that the discrepancy between the two schemes depends on both $\Delta t$ and $\Delta x$.